# Perl to read the config value properly for comma separated values

Tags: perl, config

Config file:

```
rb_acc=country of account opening #,Global #,country_account_open
rb_adv=adverse media information #,Global #,adverse_info_flag,adverse_info_severity,adverse_info_date
rb_arm=account relationship manager #,Global #,arm_code,count_of_clients
```

My reading routine:

```
sub read_header{    
    open my $header_file, '<', $header_configuration_path or die "Can not open '$header_file': $OS_ERROR"; 
    while (<$header_file>) {        
        chomp;                 
        s/#.*//;               
        s/^\s+//;               
        #s/\s+$//;              
        next unless length;    
        my ($var, $val) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $_, 2);
        $data{$var} = $val;
    }
    close $header_file;

    print "Data values\n";
    print Dumper \%data;

}
```

My output is coming like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'rb_acc' => 'country of account opening
rb_adv=adverse media information #,Global #,adverse_info_flag,adverse_info_severity,adverse_info_date
rb_arm=account relationship manager #,Global #,arm_code,count_of_clients'

        };
```

But i need something like

```
rb_acc=>country of account opening #,Global #,country_account_open
rb_adv=>adverse media information #,Global #,adverse_info_flag,adverse_info_severity,adverse_info_date
rb_arm=>account relationship manager #,Global #,arm_code,count_of_clients
```

Please help.

The split i use is not working i guess i am new to perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one error is in the regex intended to remove comment lines: it needs an anchor; as it stands it finds the first `#` anywhere on the line and removes it with everything that follows.

Other than that, I don't see how you get the reported output.  Perhaps it's something else in the program, since your sub (apparently) picks up some `%data` from outside scope? Just that possibility is enough of a reminder to always declare your variables in the smallest scope. <sup>†</sup>

The program, with a few other fixes (and some personal preferences)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump qw(dd);

sub read_header {
    my ($file) = @_; 

    my %data;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;    
        s/^\s*#.*//;    
        s/^\s+//;            #/
        next if not length;    
        my ($var, $val) = split /\s*=\s*/; 
        $data{$var} = $val;
    }   
    close $fh;
    return \%data;
}

my $file = shift || die "Usage: $0 config-file\n";

my $data = read_header($file);

dd $data;
```

prints

```
{
  rb_acc => "country of account opening #,Global #,country_account_open",
  rb_adv => "adverse media information #,Global #,adverse_info_flag,adverse_info_severity,adverse_info_date",
  rb_arm => "account relationship manager #,Global #,arm_code,count_of_clients",
}
```

The needed variables -- `$file` and `%data` -- are declared and passed (in and out of function), as you should always do. 
Since in this case there is no need to limit the number of terms that `split` is to return I removed that.

I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to print data.

---

<sup>†</sup>   As `mob` notes, that output can be produced by undefining the [input record separator `$/`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/), along with `s/#.*//` which removes the first hash and all else (to the first newline, since the `.` doesn't match a newline).
This means that `$/` is undefined elsewhere in the program as a global (instead of being [`local`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html)-ized to that scope), what is likely wrong and need be fixed; using the function from this post in that program would still fail.

Comment: You could get that output if you fubared `$/`

Comment: This is my first program in perl I ll do well keeping this in mind thanks

Comment: @mob Ah, yes! Added a comment

Comment: not working for me please help i still get $VAR1 = {
          'rb_acc' => 'country of account opening #,Global #,country_account_open
rb_adv'
        };

Comment: @javalearner Did you see the comment I added at the end? It seems that the global variable `$/` is undefined somewhere else in your program (it can be directly set to `undef`, for example). Once that is done, any files that are read (anywhere in the program!) are read whole, not line by line. So look for that.  If you copy-paste the program I posted here, does it work as expected?

Comment: Oh local $/ like that I have used in my other sub is that the issue how to define that $/

Comment: @javalearner  Ah, there we go.  So: if you have `local $/;` in your other sub then that makes `$/` undefined _only in that sub_ (more precisely, within the smallest scope it's in).   But, do you possibly have something like `$/ = undef;` somewhere (without `local`)?

Comment: @javalearner  You _can_ simply say `$/ = "\n";` at the beginning of this sub and it will work.  But you _really want to find_ where `$/` is messed with in a way so that it affects it in this sub.

Comment: @javalearner  The [`$/` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/) sets what the end-of-line is, loosely speaking. It's normally set to `"\n"` of course.  So once it gets undefined, there is no end-of-line (so to say) so each file is just read whole, at once. This is what you do when you want to read the whole file into a scalar; but then you do `local $/;` so that `$/` is undefined only within the smallest scope in which that statement is (that's what `local` does).  Otherwise ... the `$/` is a "global" variable so if you simply change it then it's changed in the whole program!